# "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" error for one user on only some downloads

Tags: .net, vb.net, ssl, webclient

I have an app in beta written in VB.NET 4.7. The installer downloads files needed to run the main app. This includes the app.exe and 3 .zip files. My "fileservers" are mediafire.com and github.com. All urls are https.

The code is simple, basically

```
        Using client As New WebClient
                Try
                    client.DownloadFile(latestInfo("filelink"), installDir & "\application.exe")
                Catch ex As Exception
                    <catch code here>
                End Try
            For i = 1 To CInt(latestInfo("librarylinks"))
                Dim filename = latestInfo(i & "filename")
                    Try
                        client.DownloadFile(latestInfo(i & "filelink"), installDir & "\" & filename)
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        Clipboard.SetText(latestInfo(i & "filelink"))
                        If MsgBox($"There was an error downloading a critical resource file - you can try to download it manually - the link is {latestInfo(i & "filelink")} (Press Ctrl-V to paste into your browser). Download it to {installDir} and press OK when done or Cancel to cancel the installation", vbCritical + vbOKCancel, "FILE NOT FOUND") = vbCancel Then
                            Exit Sub
                        End If
                    End Try
                    If LCase(filename).EndsWith("zip") AndAlso File.Exists(installDir & "\" & filename) Then
                        Unzip(installDir & "\" & filename)
                        File.Delete(installDir & "\" & filename)
                    End If
            Next
        End Using
```

I've very rarely had any exceptions - occasionally when the server is down. I have never had a SSL error. I have multiple users, most of whom have never had an SSL error. I have one new user from Belgium (I'm in the US - users are in multiple countries) who cannot install. When I got a look at his logs, it looks like the application downloads fine, then he gets a SSL error on the resource files (in the For loop).

The fileserver for the application and 2 of the resource files is mediafire. The fileserver for one of the resource files is github.

What could possibly explain this error that only one user gets and not even on every file download using the client? The answers I've seen that talk about security protocol should give an error every time, right? I'm nervous about adding "SecurityProtocolType.Tls12" and potentially messing other users up that are not currently experiencing issues.

Unfortunately I'm very limited on solutions I can try because I can't replicate the issue myself and because while the user is patient, he's not really up for a long debugging session and is also 6 hours ahead of me. So I'm hoping to find a potential cause I can test using a log to validate the reason.

Comment: What if you target .Net 4.8?  Can't remember exactly where in the .net versions TLS1.2 became fully supported.  I'm have heard best practice is to not try forcing TLS version support and allow the transport mechanisms to resolve the best option themselves

Comment: Retrieving the full stacktrace and/or enabling debugging for the TLS implementation would give much more information; currently the error in the title is completely void of the cause of this error.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes absolutely - any advice how to enable tls debugging on a user's system?  What do you mean by the full stacktrace exactly - this error is all that I get returned.

Comment: Well, I hope you can somehow get a better error report from the applications you've yourself been distributing. Because as it stands it might as well be a network or proxy issue.

Comment: Sorry was it not clear that I'm trying to find out how to get more information to narrow it down?